# Core Data 3 read and write data from index

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
do{
  cards = try context.fetch(Card.fetchRequest()).
  }
catch{
  print(error)
  }
```

This code reads whole massive data. What if i wanna read only from id. Like here "id == %@". How to do this? And how edit data from id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<MenuItems>(entityName: "MenuItems")
let filters = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)

request.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [filters])

let results = (try? context.fetch(request)) ?? []
```

You can add more `NSPredicate`'s to `filters` if you wish.